# MySQL extractvalue too short and cutting off query result

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, sql-injection

**EDIT BELOW**

So I have been spending a few hours tryng to solve this but just can't find a sulotion. I am doing a school assignment about SQL Injection. I am trying to query out all the database names, tables names, column names and column and row data. I am successfully querying this data out to the web page I am injecting from. Just a small problem. The query result on the web page is too short and does not show the complete query and is cutting it off. Just to be clear. The website does not display any data from the database. The only way to make it show data from the database is by error based injection.

It is extracting the content of the columns of one row but not showing the complete returned message.

[image: Result of above written code snippet]

This is my SQL query I inject into the web page.

```
' AND extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(SELECT concat(0x3a ,firstname, 0x3a,lastname,0x3a,email, 0x3a,username,0x3a,password) FROM users LIMIT 0,1))); #
```

The intented query of the web page:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'username' AND password = 'password'
```

The full SQL query that will be executed with my injection part:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '' AND extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(SELECT concat(0x3a ,firstname, 0x3a,lastname,0x3a,email, 0x3a,username,0x3a,password) FROM users LIMIT 0,1))); # AND password = ''
```

Is there any way to make the extractvalue to show a longer error message to show the complete result of SELECT concat? Part of the email, username and password is missing. I can get this by choosing smaller amount of columns to query out but I want to be able query a whole row at once. I can query it but I just can't get it to show the whole query on the web page.

Any alternatives? The database server is running MariaDB version 10.3.35

**EDIT**

So here is also image of the only way into the database
[image: Only way into the sepsite]

And the website is created with PHP.

Comment: To append to the results you'll need a `UNION ALL` as part of your syntax and then another SELECT that has the the desired output. It may not be possible to just `;` / `#` the password at the end, so another `UNION ALL SELECT ` where it doesn't matter if there are any results from this query. The XPATH syntax error indicates however some XPATH processing is done, so you need to see/observe how that is being applied to your input.

Comment: I think I know how to use the `UNION ALL` now but I get the message `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`. The query string I tried is `' UNION ALL SELECT NULL,concat(0x28,username,0x3a,password,0x29) FROM users #`. What should I change?

Comment: Your `UNION ALL SELECT` need to return the same number of columns as `SELECT * FROM users`

Comment: Never mind. I just found a solution that works and still is error based. I found a solution that does not use extractvalue but double query `' AND(SELECT 1 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),concat(0x3a,(SELECT concat(0x3a,firstname,0x3a,lastname,0x3a,email,0x3a,username,0x3a,password) FROM users LIMIT 0,1),FLOOR(rand(0)*2))x FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY x)a) #`. But thank you trying to help me :)